# Set window scroll bar to contain inner div, and disable it for the rest of the body

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I try to display something like what is done on some famous sites: to display a picture + comment text in an overlaying div, so when I do this I like to disable scrolling for the rest of the body , and the window scrollbars adjust to allow me only to scroll in the overlaying div.

I have all the page content in a div called id = bodyDiv, so a bad solution could be to set the height of the bodyDiv to "100%" and appending the overlaying div directly under body. The problem with this is when I scroll the content of my page to a certain position and then want to show an image in the overlaying div bodyDiv scrolls back to the original position scroll = 0.

Can you please give me a JavaScript and CSS based solution for that?

I have no initial code to treat this problem. The concept can be clear if we see a facebook publication for example, when we click on a picture we get a floating "div" (I suppose) on which the picture (in bigger size) is on the left and comment on right, the browser scroll bars adapt to allow only scrolling inside that div, once we close the publication (that div) the scroll bar returns as it was before (same position too).

This is what I want to achieve. I can achieve partly to adapt scroll bar to the div to the overlaying div this way:

```
document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.overflow = "hidden";
document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.height = "100%";
```

and then return to normal scroll :

```
    document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.height = "auto";
    document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.overflow = "auto";
```

but after closing the publication the body (normal) scroll return to 0. I want to keep the scroll where I left it before viewing the page.

Comment: Provide us some codes to play with, your explanations are partially vague to me. Plus without no code, I don't get to truly understand your intention ....

Comment: who are those STUPID PEOPLE here just downvoting without comment or solution.. show up sewerage rats

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to pick out precisely what you're going for, but it sounds like you're clearly out of the intended scope of the browser-based bars.

Why don't you look into something like [NiceScroll](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/)? It's a jQuery plugin, so you have enormous control over what\how it works.

I've done some pretty rich stuff with it: conditional styling, manual positioning, so on and so on....

Comment: thank you, until now i managed to write my code jquery free. i don't know if good or bad decision. a choice, i even added some NiceScroll like scroll bars to my inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution it works fine with one exception I will mention at the end. First save the scroll position before displaying the image:

```
scrollPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.overflow = "hidden";
document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.height = "100%";
```

than scroll the window to the saved position when closing the overlaying div:

```
document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.height = "auto";
document.getElementById("bodyDiv").style.overflow = "auto";
window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
```

This can be surely adapted to support x and y scrolling. It works very fine (the scroll is set back with pixel's precision) with one thing is that at time the picture is displayed on the screen the background which is still partly visible on the edges seem to be shifted a bit.
I don't know what is the reason for this; except this I'm satisfied with the result.